# Check for IPV6 in layers in pyshark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyshark

I am trying to use pyshark to put all of the ip src or dst into a list, which I later want to graph with matplotlib, to see which IP addresses sent or received the most traffic(not trying to do both at once). However, when I iterate through the packets of my capture, I print the list after each packet until I hit an IPV6 packet(I think) with a destination address of 'ff02::fb', and I get an error that says "KeyError: 'layer does not exist in packet'" I am trying to find a way around this so I can graph the results.

```
cap = pyshark.FileCapture('p-02.pcap')
ipList = []

for packet in cap:
    if ("IP" in str(packet.layers)):
        thisip = packet['ip'].dst
        ipList.append(thisip)
        print(ipList)
```

Here are the results:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j769.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IPv6` packets are in the `IPV6 Layer` in `packet.layers`

and standard IPv4 packers are in the `IP Layer` in `packet.layers`

Here is some basic code to access these packets.

```
import pyshark 

capture = pyshark.FileCapture(input_file='your_pcap_file_name')
for packet in capture:
    if 'IPV6 Layer' in str(packet.layers):
        print('do something with IPV6 packets')
    if 'IP Layer' in str(packet.layers):
        print('do something with IPV4 packets')
```

output

```
do something with IPV4 packets
do something with IPV6 packets
do something with IPV4 packets
do something with IPV6 packets
do something with IPV4 packets
```

Also here is an older `Github` Project that I did on using `Pyshark` for [packet analysis](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/pyshark_packet_analysis).  I'm in the process of updating this project with more formal documentation.